# ggplot2: How to use geom_line() to connect all points when y is factor?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to connect all the points by the order of my `x values`. It works fine if the `y values` are not discrete(factor) as below:

```
df = read.csv("result.csv")
qplot(x=1:100, y=df$process[1:100]) + geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    ggtitle("First 100 Process Schedule") + xlab("Quanta") + ylab("Process")
```

[image: f1]

Once I changed the `y values` to factor, `geom_line()` only connects points sharing the same `y value`. I am wondering how to make the plot look like the first plot but with factorized `y vaules`?

```
df = read.csv("result.csv")
df$process = factor(df$process)
qplot(x=1:100, y=df$process[1:100]) + geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    ggtitle("First 100 Process Schedule") + xlab("Quanta") + ylab("Process")
```

[image: f2]

Comment: Is there a reason you need the y-values to be factor?

Comment: @eipi10 My y-values are discrete, and I don't really want to have 3.5 and 4.5 there. Are there anyway to remove values on y axis?

Comment: No need for factors. Just add `+ scale_y_continuous(breaks=2:6)`.

Comment: @eipi10 wow it works like magic. Thanks!

Comment: If you simply want to plot values in order of `x`, use `geom_line` with `group = 1`, i.e. `d <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE))`; `ggplot(d, aes(x, factor(y))) + geom_line(aes(group = 1))`

Comment: See `?aes_group_order`: "By default, the group is set to the interaction of all discrete variables in the plot."